# UI Elements Not Rendering Properly on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game, UI elements not rendering properly on an Android device.
But it working properly within Unity Editor. 
Here is the example of this problem I am facing:

[image]

I have purchased old source code and then upgraded its source code to Unity 2018 version.
I have implemented a Canvas based UI system from scratch and completed all UI screens.

At last, I have run the game in actual Android device but I was shocked by getting above result.
I have checked all things as per my knowledge but all properties values are proper.

Here you have one object selected to show its inspector.
[image]

So please give me some suggestion to correct above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `UI/Default` shader is present. `Project Settings > Graphics > Built-in Shader Settings`

[image]

Comment: Amazing it worked now in mobile device :) why it was working in Unity editor that I can't able to understand? If you have a little bit more information then please add within the answer.

Comment: @Siddharth Most likely an error while upgrading to a different version of Unity.

Comment: @Siddharth also, as far as I know, the editor has access to all of the resources in the project, while the build is trying to only use the resources that you absolutely need.